# Which brain disorders cause better second language learning?

Tags: psycholinguistics, second-lang-acquisition, neurolinguistics

I heard that people with some types of synesthesia may have advantages for learning second languages. I don't know whether it’s true or not. Which kind of brain disorders cause better second-language learning, especially in adults?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the language acquisition. Please try asking it on [languagelearning.se] instead.

Comment: Synesthesia isn't a brain disorder.